# Two GridViews, Copy Sizing Data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two grid views on an ASP.NET webform. I am using C# all server side no JS.

I am trying to copy the sizing data (width, ControlStyle, FooterStyle HeaderStyle, ItemStyle) from the first GridView, to the second so that the two always stays the same size. Is there a more effective way than having to iterate through everything to achieve this (every column, etc.)? These grids display different data, within different headers but have the same column count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set it in the declaration (on a page), but in the code behind - that way any changes to one get also applied to the other one as well:
 `GridView1.Width = GridView2.Width = 728;`

Or:
`GridView2.Width = GridView1.Width;`